# django-tastypie custom serialization for fetching only one entry

Tags: django, json, serialization, tastypie

I have a model with a custom json serializer that performs some processing prior to dumping to json.

Now, when fetching a single obj i want to use the custom serializer from the model to fetch the entire object (with the processing mentioned above). When fetching a list i want to use the default serializer to fetch only the headers (render only the model fields).

I looked into three options

**overriding `obj_get`**

```
def obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        obj = ComplexModel.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        return obj.to_serializable()
```

i got thrown with

```
{"error": "The object LONG JSON DUMP has an empty attribute 'description' and doesn't allow a default or null value."}
```

not sure why this is happening - the field `description` is nullable, Plus - why tastypie is checking validation for objects already in the database, and... while fetching ??

**using `dehydrate`**

```
 def dehydrate(self, bundle):
            return bundle.obj.to_serializable()
```

This is great but the cycle is executed before each object - so i cann't tell if I'm fetching a list or a single object. The result here is the full serizliazed objects whether it's a list or a single entry.

**creating a custom serializer**

```
  class CustomComplexSerializer(Serializer):
        def to_json(self, data, options=None):
            if isinstance(data,ComplexModel):
                data = data.to_serializable()
            return super(CustomComplexSerializer,self).to_json(data)
```

Same problem here, when fetching one entry the serializer accepts the obj in `data.obj`, when it's fetching a list it accepts a dict (odd...). I can check if bundle is an instance of dict as well - but testing for the type of `ComplexModel` felt awkward enough.

So what is the best way to implement a custom serialization for fetching only a single entry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, I think i found the right way to do this and it's by using `full_dehydrate`.

```
 def full_dehydrate(self, bundle, for_list=False):
        if not for_list:
            return bundle.obj.to_serializable()
        return super(ReportResource,self).full_dehydrate(bundle,for_list)
```